# Java Actionlistener on JButton with no name?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have this java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        panel.add(new Label("south"));
        panel.add(new Button("Press here :)"));


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(loader);
        frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(loader);
        //frame.getContentPane().addMouseMotionListener(loader);
        frame.pack();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Deleted some unimportant content

        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.add("south", panel);

        t.start();
    }
```

So I have this frame which has one button that currently does nothing. I have been looking quite a lot on the internet for a solution but I can't figure out how to add an actionlistener to the button since it has no name? Like how would I tell what button is pressed with an actionlistener? Besides that, I believe I have to implement it and therefore I thought it might be a bad idea to do this in the main method? I just wanted to try it out before moving it to another class or method.

Well, I hope you can provide me with some suggestions or advice, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at this line:

```
panel.add(new Button("Press here :)"));
```

You create a new button and pass it to the `add` method of `panel`. If you want to do anything with the button, such as adding an `ActionListener` to it, then first create the button and assign it to a variable, before passing it to `panel.add`:

```
// Create a Button and assign it to a variable
JButton button = new JButton("Press here :)");

// Add an action listener to the button
button.addActionListener(...);

// Add the button to the panel
panel.add(button);
```

This is basic Java programming knowledge. See Oracle's tutorial, for example the one about [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), for more information on how to work with objects and variables.

Comment: `Button` in answer code changed to `JButton`. @PHPeter: please note this because this is important. You don't want to mix Swing and AWT components without good reason and good foresight.